# Pandas: how to GROUPBY by number of not NaNs for each row?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a result from check-all-that-apply questions:

```
A   |  B  | C ...
1   | NaN | 1
NaN |  1  | NaN
```

Where `NaN` means the responder did not select that option, and `1` if they selected it.

I want to group by the number of not NaNs in each row. Specifically, this is the kind of output visualization I am trying to do:
[image: Groupby distribution]

I tried using `count()`:

```
df.count(axis=1).reset_index()
```

And I get the number of selected boxes per user, but I don't know what's next.

Comment: Can you add more data and a graph that represent that data?

Comment: so your x-axis is your row-number index?

Comment: do `pd.cut` or `value_counts` on `df.count(axis=1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the dataframe is like this, I included 1 more row so that we get values of 4+ :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,np.nan,1,np.nan],
                   'B':[np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan],
                   'C':[np.nan,1,1,np.nan],
                  'D':[np.nan,np.nan,1,np.nan]})
```

`df.isna().sum(axis=1)` would give you the count for number of NAs per row. But you want to be these values, you can use `pd.cut` :

```
labels = pd.cut(df.isna().sum(axis=1),[-np.inf,1,3,+np.inf],labels=['0-1','2-3','4+'])
labels

0    2-3
1    2-3
2    0-1
3     4+
```

And just plot this:

```
ax = (labels.value_counts(sort=False) / len(labels)).plot.bar()
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(lambda y, _: '{:.0%}'.format(y)))
```

[image]